# R how to use fun.aggregate to keep only middle values

Tags: r, aggregate, dcast

I have a dataframe of the form:

| col1 | var | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | VAR1 | 1 |
| B | VAR1 | 2 |
| C | VAR1 | 3 |
| A | VAR2 | 4 |
| B | VAR1 | 5 |
| A | VAR1 | 6 |
| A | VAR1 | 7 |

I have applied following dcast without fun.aggregate:
`dcast(dataframe, col1~var, value.var="value")`

Iam getting following error:
`Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length`

I cant figure out what fun.aggregate to put to get the middle values (not median).

I want to get the following dataframe after dcast with suitable fun.aggregate:

| col1 | VAR1 | VAR2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 6 | 4 |
| B | 2 | 0 |
| C | 3 | 0 |

Comment: How is 2 the "middle value" of (2, 5) for col1 = B ? Your logic is not clear.

Comment: @neilfws if there is only even number of values, I need to round it to the `no of entries/2` th position value.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own function which checks the middle value and pass that function to `fun.aggregate` in `dcast` like this:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "col1   var value
A   VAR1    1
B   VAR1    2
C   VAR1    3
A   VAR2    4
B   VAR1    5
A   VAR1    6
A   VAR1    7
", header = TRUE)

library(data.table)
# Create your own function
middle <- function(x) {
  if(length(x) > 1) {
  sort(x)[ceiling(length(x) / 2)]
  }
  else {
  sort(x)[ceiling(length(x) / 2 + 0.1)]
  }
}

dcast(df, col1~var, value.var="value", fun.aggregate = middle)
#>   col1 VAR1 VAR2
#> 1    A    6    4
#> 2    B    2   NA
#> 3    C    3   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>